# Show only 1 Post in WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

i have a custom query :

```
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'reply',
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($arg);
if($my_query -> have_posts()){
    while ($my_query -> have_posts()){
          $my_query -> the_post(); } }
```

I want to show one post in this page? how i can limit this query to show 1 post?
*when i use posts_per_page => 1 not works and 10 post is shown.

Comment: a silly workaround is to get rid of the while loop and use only `$my_query -> the_post();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$arg = array(
    "post_type" => "reply",
    "numberposts" => 1, //how many posts to query from DB
    "posts_per_page" => 1 // how many posts to display per page
}
```

I explained in the code what each does.

Comment: in what way it doesn't work @Majid? Could you post a var_dump of the entire $my_query please?